# Outlook signature that creates more text on click

Tags: email, outlook, email-attachments

I want a signature on Outlook that has a section to say "Click here", and upon doing so, displays more text.

I thought about hyperlinking to a separate signature with the desired text, but can't link to the necessary multiple files, and I don't think the recipient would have access to the second signature files unless they were somehow stored in the email.

Is there any possible way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but I do not think this can be done in other ways except linking "Click here" to an external source (url) where the content is displayed.

Outlook (and email in general) has various limitations in terms of markup support so there is no way of achieving exactly what you want here.

Comment: That's what I assumed. I'll keep the question open slightly longer just in case though, thank you.